# How to cross-compile libFLAC as a shared library?

Tags: shared-libraries, cross-compiling, autotools, flac

I am trying to cross-compile [libFLAC](http://flac.sourceforge.net/) for Windows from Linux. Here are the steps I have performed:

1. I downloaded the latest release (1.2.1) and extracted the tarball.
2. I applied [a small patch](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1161417/):

   ```
   patch -p0 < my_patch.diff
   ```
3. I ran the following command in the extracted directory:

   ```
   ./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32
               --prefix=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32
               --enable-shared
   ```
4. I then ran `make` and waited for the library to build.
5. Although there were no errors during the build process, a shared library is not built - all I end up with is a static library (despite explicitly requesting one in the `./configure` step above). If I run `make install`, I end up with the following files / directories:

   [image]

The output of the two commands is available here:

- `configure`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1161368/
- `make`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1161427/

---

**Edit:** if I use the option `--disable-static`, I get this output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1161441/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to switch from the 1.2.1 release to a checkout of [git://git.xiph.org/flac.git](http://git.xiph.org/flac.git/).

...and I am pleased to report that the library now compiles without issue and I end up with a `libFLAC-8.dll` file.